# Repetition and 'think for yourself what...'

Tags: grammar, repetition

'After 20 seconds, when the first printed words appeared, I found out what the message of the video was. In my opinion, this is a good timing, because you must first think for yourself what message SIRE wants spread with this video.'

The fragment, which I have written myself, is about a commercial from SIRE (company) called "Hands off our social workers".

I have two questions about this fragment. First, how do I avoid the repitition of' video'? And second, is it correct to use 'what' with 'think for yourself'?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "printed words",  do you mean words on the screen? Those aren't printed. Printed words are words on paper not on a screen.

Comment: Oh, really? Yeah but I mean words on the screen during a video.

Comment: Technically those are "titles".  But that is a technical use of the word, though "subtitles" has entered common use, and you sometimes hear "end titles" for the scrolling credits at the end of a film.  You should probably use "**caption**" for the text on screen in a commercial, if writing for a general audience.

Comment: I don't mean subtitles, I mean a fragment which consists only of words on the screen which give the message of the video.

Comment: What if you leave the second 'video' out of the sentence.. You would get 'first think for yourself what message SIRE wants to spread' (or 'wants to get across').